# How are judges chosen in MMA/UFC fights?

Tags: rules, officiating, mma

Judges in MMA sometimes make questionable decisions over bouts. So I was wondering, what exactly makes a person qualify to be a judge on professional MMA fights? What criteria is set for someone to be a judge in an MMA/UFC bout?

Comment: Judges and referees need a license depending on the event they're officiating. Officials have profound knowledge of the sport and all techniques, since that's a basic requirement in order to get certified.